# How to force JBoss 4.2.3 to clear hibernate's session cache for every request?

Tags: hibernate, caching, jboss, entitymanager

It seems to me that JBoss reuses entity managers and the underlying hibernate sessions for multiple requests. I have run a test which proves that in some cases the state of an entity may be out-dated even if it is just fetched using `em.find()`.

How can I disable this behaviour and force to clear or throw away used sessions to ensure that each request is handled with clear cache?

**UPD:**

Here is an example case.

HTTP request 1. A session bean creates an entity instance and stores it with field "A" set to value 1. The persisted entity gets ID = 4.

HTTP request 2. A session bean looks up an entity with ID = 4, sets its field "A" to value 2 and saves it.

HTTP request 3. A session bean looks up an entity with ID = 4 and checks it's field "A". If the value is 1 it does one thing, if it is 2 it does another thing.

In case if the EM in request 3 happens to be the same as in request 1, an undesired behavior occurs. I have tested this and got approx. 10% cases of failure.

Comment: I have updated the question with an example explaining why

Comment: Artem, it seems you're using an extended persistence context (which is bound to session bean lifecycle and thus will have the behavior you're describing) but you want transaction-scoped one instead: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/entitymanager/reference/en/html/architecture.html#architecture-ejb-persistctxscope.

Comment: I do not specify the PersistenceContextType explicitly in my @PersistenceContext annotation. As far as I know, Transaction-scope is the default. And all my session beans are stateless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured this out. JBoss handles sessions correctly, there was a bug in my test =) Sorry, and thanx for your help

Answer (score 0):

Did you try **[evicting](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#evict%28java.lang.Object%29)** the **Object** from the **[Session](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/Session.html)** ?

Comment: How and when(where) would you do that to achieve the goal I have stated in the question?